# How to remove a series from box-plot data?

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, seaborn

Hello I'm trying to solve this question with python and seaborn : Use "seaborn" to create box plots to represent the number of pieces per decade. We will not use the decade of the 40s because it only contains one year. **

The decades are starting from 1940 to 2010 and I would like to know how to delete the first decade (1940) from my boxplot.

Here this is what I did :

```
piecesDecade = sns.boxplot(x = "decade", y ="pieces" , data = lego)
```

but I dont know how to not use the first decade !

here the output of lego :

[image: output lego]

Comment: Would help to know what the format of `lego` is.

Comment: It's a csv imported with panda.read_csv

Comment: Can you edit your post with the output that shows when you type `lego` in the console?

Answer (score 1):

You can just filter out the decades:

```
sns.boxplot(x = "decade", y ="pieces" , data = lego[lego['year'] > 1949])
# or data = lego[lego['decade'] != '1940s']
```